# Parsing data or executing data Errror

Tags: java, android

I have this application the app bring data from database and store it in a list view then every record have a history i want when i click on the record in the ListView to show me the history of that record.  for now i made it when i click on a record then click find id button it will give me the id of the record then i will click History to clear this ListView and showing the history of this record on the same ListView.
 [Screen Shot for the app1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ1EJ.png) ,
[Screen Shot for the app2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssQmL.png)

Any one Can help me, my app run but when i want to show the history it don't pass this (if) i don't know why

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if(integer == 1){

            ArrayAdapter<String > adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(c,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, patients );
            lv.setAdapter(null);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Snackbar.make(view,patients.get(i), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to parse data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

the PHP side

```
<?php
$host='127.0.0.1';
$username='root';
$password='';
$database='app';

$con =mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die ('unable to connect');

if (mysqli_connect_error($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error();

}
$patientID = $_GET['patientID'];
$query= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM history where 
   patientID='$patientID' ");

if ($query)
{

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $flag[]= $row;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
}

mysqli_close($con);



    ?>
```

HistoryDownloader Java Class

```
public class HistoryDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {





    Context c;
    String address;
    ListView lv;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    public HistoryDownloader(Context c, String address, ListView lv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.address = address;
        this.lv = lv;

    }

    //Before the job start

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(c);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Fetch Data");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching data .... Please wait ");
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... strings) {
        String data= downloadData();

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        progressDialog.dismiss();


        if (s != null){

            HistoryParser h= new HistoryParser(c,lv,s);
            h.execute();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unable to download data ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private  String downloadData(){
        //connect and get a stream

        InputStream is= null;
        String line =null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            is =new BufferedInputStream( con.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer() ;

            if(br !=null){
                while((line=br.readLine()) !=null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");

                }

            }
            else{
                return null;

            }
            return  sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (is != null){
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return  null;
    }
}
```

HistoryParser java Class

```
public class HistoryParser  extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    String lls;
    Context c;
    ListView lv;
    String data;

    ArrayList<String > patients= new ArrayList<>();

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public HistoryParser (Context c, ListView lv, String data) {
        this.c = c;
        this.lv = lv;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(c);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Parser");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Parsing the data ... please wait");
        progressDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        return this.histoParse();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if(integer == 1){

            ArrayAdapter<String > adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(c,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, patients );
            lv.setAdapter(null);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Snackbar.make(view,patients.get(i), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to parse data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    // parse the reciv
    private int histoParse (){
        try {
            //adding the data  to json aray first
            JSONArray js= new JSONArray(data);

            //create json object to hold a singel item
            JSONObject jo= null;

            patients.clear();

            // loop the array
            for(int i=0 ;i<js.length();i++){
                jo= js.getJSONObject(i);
                //retriving the name
                //TODO: write the strring depend on the column name in the database
                // write the strring depend on the column name in the database
                String case1=jo.getString("case1");
               /* String case2=jo.getString("case2");
                String case3=jo.getString("Case3");
                String case4=jo.getString("Case4");
                String case5=jo.getString("Case5");
                String case6=jo.getString("Case6");
                String case7=jo.getString("Case7");
                String case8=jo.getString("Case8");
                String case9=jo.getString("Case9");
                String case10=jo.getString("Case10");
                String trt1=jo.getString("trt1");
                String trt2=jo.getString("trt2");
                String trt3=jo.getString("trt3");
                String trt4=jo.getString("trt4");
                String trt5=jo.getString("trt5");
                String trt6=jo.getString("trt6");
                String trt7=jo.getString("trt7");
                String trt8=jo.getString("trt8");
                String trt9=jo.getString("trt9");
                String trt10=jo.getString("trt10");




                //add it to our array list
                patients.add("Patient History");
                patients.add("");
                patients.add("Cases");
             patients.add("");
                */   patients.add(case1);
             /*   patients.add(case2);
                players.add(case3);
                players.add(case4);
                players.add(case5);
                players.add(case6);
                players.add(case7);
                players.add(case8);
                players.add(case9);
                players.add(case10);
                players.add("");
                players.add("Treatments");
                players.add("");
                players.add(trt1);
                players.add(trt2);
                players.add(trt3);
                players.add(trt4);
                players.add(trt5);
                players.add(trt6);
                players.add(trt7);
                players.add(trt8);
                players.add(trt9);
                players.add(trt10);
*/

            }
            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;

    }



}
```

Main Class  Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    String url="http://10.0.2.2/Android/Fetch.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        final ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        final Downloader d= new Downloader(this,url,lv);
        String urlHistory="http://10.0.2.2/Android/History.php?patientID="+textView.getText().toString().trim();
        final HistoryDownloader dd= new HistoryDownloader(this,urlHistory,lv);

        final Button btn= (Button ) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final Button btn2=(Button)  findViewById(R.id.button2);



        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lv.setAdapter(null);
                //String kk=textView.getText().toString().trim();
              dd.execute();
                if(textView.getText() != ""){

                }else{

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i did not use Transmitting Network Data **Volley** thats why im getting   :)